# Microsoft.Reporting does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, report

I have developed project in `VS2010` and now I want to continue same project with `VS2012` but I'm getting Error: `Microsoft:Reporting does not exists in namespace`

I am using Microsoft Reports for developing reports.
Please Help me if you have any solution.

Comment: The reference may be missing. Try adding reference of Reporting to your project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Search for "reportviewer" in Nuget. Install the **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms VS2010** package.

Answer (score 7):

You must right-click on **References** folder in your project and click on **Add Reference**.
and then go to **Assemblies > Extensions > Microsoft.ReportViewer** and add it to your references.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Microsoft Report Viewer to have its assemblies available in Visual Studio. You can bring it from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442

Answer (score -1):

There might be problem with dll path. check here [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52ca4f7b-1249-42d7-96fe-48e87922564f/microsoftreportingwinformsreportviewer-is-not-defined-on-ms-build-server?forum=winformssetup)