# Execute and print ssrs pdf in C# with parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a C# program which I can call directly from my SSRS rdl file and print in PDF format. And I need to apply some paramater/s for the correct report rdl too.

How can I achieve this?

I have been googling and there are a wide range of resources and I am getting confused. And it is my very first C# program in real life. Please help me out.

Will be much appreciated any precise or similar steps by steps guides / tutorials (and) (or) any ideas for this.

Thank you.

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad. Please show us what you have tried, what output you observed and what output you expected. This way we can better help you.

Comment: I have rdl files. I just need to call them(passed parameters) and print, and I need to develop the program in c#. I saw people are talking about SOAP too. I am not quite sure about it. I am sorry I have run out of idea where to start.

Comment: Any resources to follow?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a local file, you can use the "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport" class like this.

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
...
var report = new LocalReport();
report.ReportPath = "<path to your rdlc>";
...
var bytes = report.Render("PDF", null);
```

See [Pramod Jaiswal's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717686/printing-a-report-server-side-and-silently) answer here for how to set up parameters, etc.

Note this difference between rdl and rdlc: You can simply rename the file, but you need to create local datasets in Visual Studio and bind queries to these datasets external to your report builder.
For additional info: [Converting RDL and RDLC Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I am going to take a look to that.

Comment: What references need to be installed?

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313069/microsoft-reporting-does-not-exist-in-namespace/26814748