# Missing namespace and references error in .net application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I downloaded an application from a source control and cloned to my local folder. When I tried to build the application I get to see lot of 'missing reference' errors.

> The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The log4net assembly is already added to the project but I see a warning near the assemble name

The code has a

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms
```

and I get to see

> The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What I tried:

I want to make sure VS is building the project that's being referenced. So I set the 'Build' under the Configuration to be checked.

I also tried changing the Target Framework from .Net Framework 4.0 to higher version. No luck!

Any help?

Comment: Try uninstalling/reinstalling the log4net package in your project.

Comment: Any good place to download the dll? I found one but did not see the exact dll in that

Comment: Also does that DLL support .Net Framework 4.0version?

Comment: You'll be able to see what version the DLL supports when you right-click References and select Manage Nuget packages... Searching for the package by name will show you a list of dependencies that package has. You can also see from the NuGet Gallery that log4net has no dependencies for .NET Framework 4.0 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/)

Comment: For your other issue, try following the selected answers from this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/17313069/1837080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Right click your solution
2- Click "Manage NuGet packages for solution"
3- Search for log4net, if it's installed, uninstall it
4- Install log4net again
5- Rebuild all